# How do I rotate an icon with CSS on hover

Tags: css

I am trying to make an icon rotate on mouse hover but can't get it to work.
I couldn't find a solution on the internet.
This is what I've tried so far:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

.material-icons:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}
button.c-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.float-right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-accordion">Section 2
      <i class="material-icons float-right">keyboard_arrow_down</i> 
  </button>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here in the code snippet, so ... what is the actual issue?

Comment: @CBroe Nope, doesn't work for me on Firefox...

Comment: @Fuross I see, but that should have been mentioned by OP in the question. It does not seem to be an issue with the specific transformation though, but that hovering over the icon does not work in general in Firefox.

Comment: I'm using firefox, so that could have been the problem indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am able to find two issues,

1. rotate is working fine in chrome, but not working in firefox.
2. transition is not smooth as mentioned by others.

So for first issue changed hover pseudo from icon to button because there is an **issue in firefox** when `<i>` used inside `button`. For second one followed as like others by adding `transition`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
.c-accordion:hover .material-icons {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

button.c-accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<button class="c-accordion">Section 2
          <i class="material-icons float-right">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

icon rotate on mouse hover on chrome but not on Mozilla Firefox same code work on my side on chrome